# Other than the rest areas for the crew - what else is in the 'attic' of an aeroplane?

Tags: airplane, crew, cabin

So I am seeing some information about crew rest areas in an aeroplane which typically just sit above the passenger cabin.

In the image of the a350 XWB for example you can see those areas in the front and back of the aeroplane.

However, what is happening in the rest of the aeroplane - is the 'attic' just sitting empty?

[image]

Image borrowed from  [FreeMan's answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27419/how-is-the-crew-rest-area-on-the-a350-accessed/27423#27423?newreg=c048b9ef29df476a9dcaf42edbb508f1) here

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's where they keep the snakes.

Answer (score 19):

The “attic” is mostly unused. The area above the passenger cabin is also called the crown area. Some aircraft do use part of it for crew rest areas. That area can also used to route electrical wiring, hydraulic lines, air conditioning, and pneumatic lines.

[Wikipedia A300 image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide-body_aircraft#/media/File:Airbus_A300_cross_section.jpg)
[image]

[Volker Gollnick photo](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Single-Aisle-Cross-Section_fig2_259895829)
[image]

Comment: Wasn't there a movie where the crown area was used by special forces soldiers to move the length of the plane unobserved by hijackers?  Completely hollywood of course.

Comment: @Criggie Air Force One of "Get off my plane!" and steven-segal-dying-after-10-minutes fame

Comment: Is this universal? I'm sure I've travelled on 3-4-3 planes that had a big dip in the ceiling above the middle seats, where one presumes stuff could happen.

Comment: Steven Seagal's was _Executive Decision_, _Air Force One_ was Harrison Ford. :) Great 90's action.

Comment: There was also a lot of crawling around in vast empty spaces in David Fincher’s *Flight Plan* starring Jodie Foster.

Comment: @CGCampbell OMG what a mistakea to makea. Course it was. But it was in fact executive decision where they were crawling around in the attic. I just got my hijacked-plane movies mixed up.

Comment: @Criggie Yeah, I'm pretty sure that false ceiling between the cabin and the crown is not strong enough to support people - it's not built to be load-bearing.  Kind of like crawling around in HVAC ducts like you see them doing in so many movies.  Most likely result is you falling through the ceiling...

Comment: A potential crossover question between here and Movies.SE... "Have there been more hijackings in real live or in movies ?"  and which is more successful.

Answer (score 12):

The "attic" elsewhere is overhead luggage bins, as on most airliners.  See the fuselage cross-section (circle, top right) and #47 in this cutaway of an A350-900, which also notes the crew rest compartments fore and aft.[image: cutaway illustration of A350]

Comment: So what you're saying is that the crew are considered carry on luggage... :)

Comment: Sure!  I bet Dick Rutan and Jeana Yeager felt like that too, after nine days!

Comment: This would mean that in the crew rest areas there are no overhead luggage compartments?